# Format of grading Witt Lie Algebra

Tags: lie-algebras, notation, modular-lie-algebras

Let $W(n,m)$ be generalized Jacobson-Witt algebra over a field of characteristic $p>3$. According to the grading of $W(n,m)$, we know that it inherits the grading from $A(n,m)$ as follows: $$W(n,m)_i=\sum_{j=1}^{n} A(n,m)_{i+1}D_j\;.$$ Consequently, $$W(n,m)=\bigoplus_{i=-1}^{s} W(n,m)_{i}$$ with $ s=\sum_ {i=1}^{n} (p^{m_i}-1)-1$.
I want to know the reason of writing the index of $A(n,m)$ in $W(n,m)_i=\sum_{j=1}^{n} A(n,m)_{i+1}D_j$ ? in fact why we must put $i+1$ ?
In the case of $p=2$ how is the grading for $W(n,m)$?

Comment: because the $D_j$ lower degree by one

Comment: it means that $D_j$ acts on $A(n,m)_{i+1}$ from left? sorry I am confused of that?